# Regex - space between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to have only two words with only one space between them. Both words must not be less than three characters. example: Joe Smith

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: what have you tried? this ain't a free coding service. maybe someone will be desperate enough to post a trivial snip, but that's not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: or "answer my homework question for me" service :-).  But we'll still help if you do your part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var tests = [
 " fail this",
 "and this ",
 "and me",
 "Pass this",
 "Fail this too",
 "three   spaces"
];

var re = /^[a-z]{3,}\s[a-z]{3,}$/i;
function isValid(str) {
  return re.test(str);
}

tests.forEach(
  function(str) {
    console.log('['+str+'] =', isValid(str));
  }
);
```

- `^` - beginning of line
- `[a-z]` - allow `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc. to `z`
- `{3,}` - Previous must be 3 or more
- `\s` - one white space. If you don't want to include all white space then change it to a space .
- `[a-z]` - allow `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc. to `z`
- `{3,}` - Previous must be 3 or more
- `$` - end of line
- `i` at the end tells it to ignore case.

Comment: In the future, ask your questions and supply examples of what you tried. Please read up on how to ask questions as mentioned by  @T.J. Crowder above.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to use with PHP? I have tried (/^(?=^.{7,32}$)[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)?$/) which works perfectly fine, but it does not make sure the first and second word is not less than 3chars